# Google Map で現在地の表示をしたい ( GoogleAPIClient ?)

Tags: android, google-maps

Android Studio 1.0 でアプリ開発を行っています。 Google Map を使用して現在地の表示を行いたいのですが、うまくいきません。原因として今まで使われていた `LocationClient` というクラスが廃止されていると分かり、代わりに `GoogleAPIClient` というクラスを用いて実装を行っていくということは分かったのですが、いかんせん参考となる情報が少なく困っています。アプリを開いたら自動的に現在地を中心とした位置まで画像を持ってくるようにしたいのですが、ご教授お願いします。

[追記]

seesaawiki.jp/w/moonlight_aska 当初は上記のサイトを参考に作成していました。
現在の状況としてGoogleMapを表示させることは出来ましたが、現在地表示まではいたっていません。

CameraPosition cameraPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
 .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).zoom(17.0f) .bearing(0).build(); 
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPos));

上記のサイトでは上のようなプログラムで現在地移動を実現していましたが、うまく動きませんでした。GoogleAPIClientの場合、targetの中にどのような‌​ものを記述していけばいいのでしょうか

[追・追記]
うまく表示させることに成功しました。GoogleAPIClientを実装することでどういった意味になるのか理解が至らず、稚拙な質問になってしまい申し訳ございませんでした。

Comment: 「[GoogleAPIClientの作成と接続](http://www.fkmsoft.jp/blog/software/android/GoogleFit/GoogleAPIClient.html)」が参考になるかもしれません。"うまくいかない"場合、"どこまでなら出来ているか"も示された方が的確な回答が付きやすいです。

Comment: 暇人の戯言です。GooglePlayServiceを利用したロケーションの取得と、地図への描写を行うAPIは別だと思っていますが、認識はあっておりますか。質問にあるコードは地図を描写するAPIで特に変わった認識はありません。掲題のソースコードを見ても、特に問題はないような……質問者様が仰っているように、むしろ、取得しているlocationの中身が問題だったりしませんか。そちらの取得処理も掲示していただけると回答する有識者が現れる気がします。

Comment: user3009331様　APIのせいで動かないとばかり思い込んでいました。locationの中身については全くの盲点でした。確認して修正してみたところうまく現在地を表示して動かすことが出来ました。ありがとうございました。